# Java library to talk to swift (OpenStack) with keystone authentication

Tags: java, openstack-swift

Is there a java library that supports swift (OpenStack) with keystone authentication?

It seems to be work in progress in JClouds but not finished yet, and cloudfiles does not seem to support it (yet) either.

Answer (score 3):

A complete overhaul of swift (called openstack-swift) is [in progress](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-299).  In the mean time, you can use any jclouds 1.7 release with the provider key "swift-keystone".

Ex.

```
view = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("swift-keystone") // or new SwiftKeystoneApiMetadata()
                     .credentials("tenantName:userName", "password")
                     .endpoint("http://localhost:5000/v2.0")
                     .buildView(BlobStoreContext.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm no longer using jclouds, so I can't confirm this at the momnent. If anybody can confirm this independently I'll tick it as right answer.

Answer (score 3):

[JOSS](http://joss.javaswift.org) is a dedicated OpenStack Swift binding for Java using Keystone authentication. On the [Github page](https://github.com/javaswift), there are several tutorials to see how it works.

Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of JOSS

Comment: As an author of JOSS, can you review the streaming upload questions on this site that are unanswered/incorrect? That is, using JOSS we noticed that the uploadObject(InputStream) method did not allow for configurable size control over the read/persistence side (buffer size on reading). It looks like JOSS reads the entire InputStream into memory prior to storage instead of streaming to persistence store in configurable sized blocks.